# Change background of li element on hover that has a current image in li

Tags: css, hover, html-lists, image

I'm made a image grid using a set of li elements and need to add a hover effect when you hover over each image in the li. I got it to work fine with the css opacity property for the .grid li a img:hover i set. When i however set a background image in here it doesn't show. Loading the browser and using the inspector shows the image loaded when i hover over it but visually it doesn't show. I tried setting the z index higher etc with no luck.

I'm open to doing this other wayys if better because each image will have its own different hover state.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<ul class="grid">
   <li><a href="link.html"><img src="images/image1.jpg"></a></li>
   <li><a href="link.html"><img src="images/image2.jpg"></a></li>
   <li><a href="link.html"><img src="images/image3.jpg"></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
ul.grid {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 20px auto 0;
  width: 798px;  
  }

.grid li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 4px 0px 0px;
  } 

.container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top:50px;
  width: 513px;
  }

.grid li a img:hover {
  background: url(images/image1_hover.jpg) no-repeat;
  }

.grid li img {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0;
  width: 262px;
  height: 200px;
  }

.grid li a {
  display: block;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you were having was related to apples and oranges. You had apples (IMG) tags on top of oranges (backgrounds)... so changing the background was working but your IMG was sitting on top of it - z-index would not help you. In this situation use background image alone.  See below.

Edited:  I see you also want them to be links.  The following will work for you.

That said, I would actually use a sprite rather than have 6 different images in this situation. And, the CSS below could likely be optimized, and certainly optimized by using LESS or SASS - but it's nearly 4 on a Friday and the company micro tap was flowing ;)

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        ul.grid {
          list-style: none;
          margin: 20px auto 0;
          width: 798px;  
        }

        .grid li {
          float: left;
          margin: 0px 4px 0px 0px;
        } 

        .container {
          margin-left: auto;
          margin-right: auto;
          margin-top:50px;
          width: 513px;
        }

        .grid li a {
          background-color: white;
          margin: 0;
          width: 50px;
          height:50px;
        }

        .grid li a {
          display: block;
          }

        .img1 {
          background: url(images/image1.jpg) no-repeat;
        }

        .img1:hover {
          background: url(images/image1_hover.jpg) no-repeat;
        }

        .img2 {
          background: url(images/image2.jpg) no-repeat;
        }

        .img2:hover {
          background: url(images/image2_hover.jpg) no-repeat;
        }

        .img3 {
          background: url(images/image3.jpg) no-repeat;
        }

        .img3:hover {
          background: url(images/image3_hover.jpg) no-repeat;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
    <ul class="grid">
       <li><a href="link.html" class="img1"></a></li>
       <li><a href="link.html" class="img2"></a></li>
       <li><a href="link.html" class="img3"></a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have an easier time using some jquery to change the source tag of your image when hovering over it.